# In visual studio 2.0, asp.net(vb), Crystal Report Creation Wizard doesn't show current connection in it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I am working on a project which is setup on 2.0 .net framework. I am working on visual studio 2005. My task is to add crystal report that list down products.

I have already installed crystal report 10. While adding new item in my solution, I can see crystal report. In this crystal report creatrion wizard on step # 2 i guess. I see option of choosing data I want to report on.

But my current connection says "No item found".

Why this is so ? How can i populate data in my record then ? Should i go for "Creates New connection"

Please help !!

Thanks...